# Can I nut-in an Ethernet connector (from 28 gauge) to 12 gauge so that I can run Ethernet out to my detached garage?

Tags: ethernet, wired

I have a detached garage that has its own electrical panel. The previous owner of the house was an electrician and it's done really well, however, there is not a very strong Wi-Fi signal in the garage.

I would like to have some smart outlets out there and such. There are 2 lines that run through the pipe that I can use (one was a 4-wire line for a house-switch to the eave lights on the garage, which also had a switch, and the other is a 3-wire spare). Currently, all, but one of the seven lines is being used by the sign off smart switch relay.

I was in the process today of swapping out the sonoff mini with a UL certified Shelly (because the sonoff failed electrical inspection, since it is not UL, certified), and I thought, "boy, I wish there was an ethernet line already running through this electrical pipe out to the garage, then I could have a wired backhaul out there".

I started thinking about it, and I thought, "huh, what if I actually just spliced in an ethernet connector and hooked up ethernet through these 12 gauge wires?"

So I started googling and I learned about powerline ethernet adapters. I'm not sure if that would be the same thing as me just splicing in ethernet connectors or not. There's no outlet involved.

I have read that you don't get very good speeds with powerline adapters, which is not an issue. I just want a couple of smart outlets and switches, etc.. and these two lines are just two of many that run out to the garage. Other than those, there are 200 W of other lines going out there that connect to the panel in the garage.

The 12 gauge wires I have are threaded.

So could this work? Can I just spice in a couple of ethernet connectors?

What are the upsides and downsides of doing this? I understand that there should be issues with regard to shielding and data loss. I don't need it to be very fast, I just need it to be reliable.

Comment: ethernet cable wire pairs must be twisted at specific number of twists per meter ... power cables will not work as ethernet cable ... there are ethernet extender devices available that plug into a powerline

Comment: Do you mean a powerline ethernet adapter? Are you saying that this adapter somehow copes with the lack of twist in the line? Do you know if they make such an adapter that can be nutted in instead of using a standard receptacle? And does that need actual AC power?

Comment: no, it does not cope with a lack of twist ... it does not turn the powerline into an ethernet cable ... it's more like a WiFi adapter that uses powerlines to communicate ... it has no battery, so it has to be plugged into a live circuit

Comment: the other thing to think about is that it is illegal in many places to run power and data cables in the same conduit ... it is also unsafe

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. You knew exactly how I was misunderstanding how it was supposed to work. So then, if I were to try one of those powerline adapters, I would have to install a receptacle on both ends. Would that mean that any outlet in the garage (and house) could potentially (with varying degrees of degraded signal) receive the signal? Or will it only work on the outlets on the same breaker/circuit? And I assume only 1 pair of adapters could work.

Comment: the two adapters may have to be on the same phase

Comment: Incidentally @jsotola, I was aware that things like phone/ethernet/etc lines shouldn't be in the same box as a power line (unless it has a divider, which I have in one shared box), at least in my township, though the inspector didn't complain about the lines running together in the same wall. He pointed out other nit-picky things and he seemed pretty observant, so I'd guess he would have said something about my data/power lines run together if that was prohibited in my township? Is the safety concern, fire? And is the restriction potentially different based on home age? Mine's built in 1920.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you can not use power cables for ethernet, otherwise why would there be special cables for it.

You can use powerline adapters.  The quality and speed of signal you get would be dependent on teh manufacturer and the price you pay.  There are caveats in some ads for them, so read it carefully.

You need at either end of the same cable (ie phase, without too many joins).  If you are only going to use the ethernet for smart switches, then it will work just fine.  For anything else, it is trial and error.

You can also use better quality WAPs or even long distance ones.   I am using an outdoor unit by Unify that easily reaches 100m.

Comment: In this context, what do "phase" and "joins" mean?

Comment: In the US (presumed by an inspector demanding a UL-listed Shelly instead of the Sonoff), residential power is delivered to your house via 2 hot wires that are 240v from each other. Each of these wires is connected to a bus in your service panel, giving you two 120v "phases" (even though it's actually single-phase). AIUI, powerline adapters work best when the transmitter and receiver are both on the same bus side in the panel. "Joins" in this case would be the number of wire nuts between the TX and Rx side of things.

Comment: If, @hepcat72, you were to put a receptacle just before the run to the shed, then another just inside the shed, both adapters would be on the same "phase" and there would only be a couple of splices ("joins") between them - from the receptacle to the wire between to the other receptacle. That would probably be the minimum number possible.